# How to list variables loaded by pkg-config in cmake

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

In Cmake when we do find_package to look up a package, how we can find the list of variables that it loads

for example

some have this format:
.._LIBRARIES

some have this format:
.._LIBS

how we can list the variables and the assigned values in that package?

Comment: Do you ask about `find_package` or `pkg-config`? These are different things.

Comment: For `find_package`, you must check the documentation of the target package. When using CMake's pkg-config support, the set variables are [documented here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html). In _**all**_ cases you should prefer to use _**imported targets**_ (e.g. `PNG::PNG`) and avoid using any of the variables at all.